# How can I fix that "_brotli" cannot be imported?

Tags: python

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\mitmdump.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\tools\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mitmproxy import exceptions, master
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\master.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mitmproxy import eventsequence
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\eventsequence.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mitmproxy import http
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\http.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mitmproxy.net import encoding
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\net\encoding.py", line 12, in <module>
    import brotli
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\brotli.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _brotli
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _brotli: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Have you tried installing it ? `pip install brotlipy`

Comment: where is the code that caused the problem ?   . . . https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example